# Append to array from variable

Tags: arrays, bash

Suppose I declare an array `Unix`

```
declare -a Unix=('Debian' 'Red hat' 'Suse' 'Fedora')
```

I can append to the array as such

```
Unix=("${Unix[@]}" "AIX")
```

I introduce another variable `a` which points to a string naming the earlier `Unix` variable

```
a=Unix
```

Can I append to the array through this second variable? The reason I want to know is I'm trying to write a function which takes a variable that 'points to an array'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `declare` builtin. Its argument undergoes expansion before the assignment is performed, so that `$a` is expanded to the name of the array to update before the assignment takes place.

```
declare "$a+=( Aix )"
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape everything so that only `a` is substituted and all else remains as is, then use `eval` -

```
Unix=('Debian' 'Red hat' 'Suse' 'Fedora')
a=Unix
eval "$a=( \"\${$a[@]}\" \"AIX\" )"
```

Comment: Unnecessary use of `eval`: `declare "$a+=( AIX )"`.